# Change JSON variables dynamically with a powershell script

Tags: json, powershell, variables, scripting, azure-powershell

The following is a test script i am running trying to have the name change on the JSON file. Below is my PowerShell script. I would like my "$test" variable to pass through to the JSON file but it is staying

**Powershell Script** PS 5.1

```
$test = "vmNAMEtest"

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
    -ResourceGroupName 'test' `
    -Name '$test' `
    -TemplateUri '.\Documents\azuredeploy.json'
```

**JSON**

```
"vmName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "simple-vm",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Name of the virtual machine."
        }
      },
```

Everytime the script is automatically the defaultValue "simple-vm" but i'd like to pass the $test value

Some things I've tried: in the JSON code:

`"defaultValue": "$test"` - this did not work

`"defaultValue": "'+$test+'"` -  also no luck

Comment: `'...'` strings are _verbatim_ strings in PowerShell, for string interpolation you need `"..."` (e.g., `"$test"`). However, to pass a variable value in isolation - even if it contains spaces - you don't need quoting at all, so simply use `$test`

Comment: As well as @mklement0's comment about quotes and string interpolation, if you want to pass a value into the ARM Template you need to pass it in the ```-TemplateParameterObject``` parameter - something like ```-TemplateParameterObject @{ "vmName" = $test }```. The ```-Name``` parameter you're currently specifying is the name of the Deployment run, not a value for the ```vmName``` parameter inside the template. Have a read of the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment?view=azps-10.1.0#description for more details...

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone @mklement0 that is extremely useful to know and I appreciate the better understanding

Comment: Thank you @mclayton for the information and documentation it was extremely helpful and I was able to get everything resolved, I appreciate the detail added and the references you made to the code I was working with, made it a lot easier to understand. Been a busy day at work so I havent been able to fully read that documentation yet but I'll be sure to get back to it tmrw, thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment, I do agree with @mclayton and below are my expected results:

```
$test = "rithwik000000"

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
    -ResourceGroupName 'rbojja' `
    -Name $test `
    -TemplateUri 'C:\Users\rbojja\Downloads\rith.json' `
    -TemplateParameterObject @{ "LogicAppName" = $test }
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: Huge thanks @Rithwik for the visualization and putting it in a use-case definitely gave me the complete understanding and a good reference point as well. I was able to get it functioning following everyone's guidance. thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 1):

thanks again to Rithwik, Mclayton, and Mklement really made everything come together, wish I could give it a thumbs up but stackoverflow is silly and wont let me because I am a noob acc. Any who here's the solution:

```
$test = "vmNAMEtest"

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
    -ResourceGroupName 'test' `
    -Name $test `
    -TemplateUri '.\Documents\azuredeploy2.json' `
    -TemplateParameterObject @{ "vmName" = $test }
```

Nothing had to be done on the JSON template side just keeping it how it is and having the place holder as a backup. Only thing I had to change was on the powershell script side. Adding TemplateParameterObject line and following what Mclayton said for the answer or visually what Rithwik said agreeing to Mclayton. One issue I was coming across when doing this was I forgot to add "`" at the end of the TemplateUri line - not allowing the code to reach the TemplateParameterObject line

**This script is extremely helpful when populating Azure subscriptions with Azure resources through powershell**

Sorry imma noob, but thanks to everyone mentioned for all your help and kindness